# Cuda 10.1 with rtx 2070 gpu on windows10 does not work when import tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

Hi I am trying to use tensorflow with cuda 10.1

I have installed cuda10.1 and CuDNN 7.5 for Cuda 10.1

When launch this command "nvcc -V" to check my installation I have this windows prompt

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Feb__8_19:08:26_Pacific_Standard_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105
```

But when I import tensorflow on jupyter notebook, I have this error

```
import tensorflow as tf;
```

Error:

```
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_100.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 10.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-90-download-archive
```

How can I do to make it work ? . thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why not just use 10.0 as recommended on the tensorflow site?

Comment: because I have this error with cuda 10 : "No supported version of Visual Studio was found. Some components of CUDA Toolkit will not work properly. Please install Visual Studio first to get the full functionality""

Comment: I just reinstalled tensorflow and cuda 10.0 with the lastest version of visual studio. From memory, it gives you a warning that not all features may work properly (nvidia NSight probably). It doesn't prevent you from continuing with the installation. Have you tried it?

Comment: I trying  from now on

Comment: I correctly when I have installed visual studio 2017 with c++

Comment: Are you saying its working now?

Comment: yes it is working

Comment: I've created an answer if you'd like to mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO fix it you need to install visual studio 2017 and cuda 10 will work

Answer (score 1):

I just reinstalled tensorflow and cuda 10.0 with the lastest version of visual studio. From memory, it gives you a warning that not all features may work properly (nvidia NSight probably). It doesn't prevent you from continuing with the installation.

Answer (score 0):

1) Uninstall CUDA 10.1 and install CUDA 10.0
2) Go to the cuDNN Archive https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive 
3) Click on Download cuDNN v7.6.1 (June 24, 2019), for CUDA 10.0
 
       (you need CUDA 10.0 installed. NOT 10.1. If you installed the wrong version, uninstall 
        it and install the 10 which works with tensorflow-gpu)
4) Click on the link for your operating system.
5) Unzip it. It should unzip to a folder called CUDA. 
6) Go into the CUDA folder and copy the contents
7) Open the installed CUDA 10 location. For windows 10 it is "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0"
 
8) Paste the contents from your clipboard to the folder.
9) have a coffee. You are done!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CUDA above 10.0 you may

- download and manually copy **cudart64_100.dll** to your **CUDA bin** folder

(A path similar to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin)

Please find the following link to download the zipfile containing the same (Extracted from CUDA 10.0)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz7ewnoc6pfxqql/cudart64_100_dll_.zip?dl=0

Once you had done this you may probably run into another error saying **cublas64_100.dll not found**. Kindly

- copy your **cublas64_10.dll** from the same folder and **rename it** to
  **cublas64_100.dll**

.